# asp.net mvc user login remembering problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am using firefox 3.63  with asp.net mvc2  in vs 2010.the thing is that in my application's userlogin form the username and password by which i login. i had the browser's remeberme save my username and password.

but the thing is that the same username and password is coming at the time of creating user(different form) with  username and password field auto populated(it had to be blank but it is not). i checked in firebug it had the value="". how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Your question isn't wholly clear to me, but aren't you now confusing a development question with (your own) browser setting (remember password)? Can you clean out your browser (cookies/passwords/etc.)?

Comment: user name and password which i saves comes in the username and password field in my user form. i really not sure how the link is formed because they have the different name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [design the HTML](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-forms/current-work/#the-autocomplete) so that the fields in the form for creating a user are not automatically populated.

You probably want these fields to be connected to the fields for logging in, since this will let your users' browsers automatically fill in the user name after creating a user, for example. (This is what in your case is copying data from the form for logging in to the form for creating a user.)